# Как достать данные из определенного объекта в JSON используя Retrofit? (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, gson

Отправляю **@GET** запрос с помощью **Retrofit** через **API** сервера и получаю **JSON** который парситься через **GSON** автоматически. Но вот проблема, необходимые мне данные хранятся в объекте "**data**" доступ к данным которому я не имею понятия как получить, умею я лишь доставать данные из **JSON** в котором только 1 объект. И теперь я могу получить лишь данные о состоянии запроса (**status**) и о характере запроса (**message**), а вот нужные данные хранятся в другом объекте **JSON'a** (**data**). **Главный вопрос: как мне получить доступ к данным из объекта data?**

*JSON который я получаю:*

```
{
   "status":200,
   "message":"rates",
   "data":{
      "USDRUB":"64.1824",
      "RUBUSD":"0.0155806",
      "EURRUB":"69.244",
      "RUBEUR":"0.0144437",
      "KZTRUB":"0.170668",
      "RUBKZT":"5.85964",
      "USDKZT":"376.086",
      "KZTUSD":"0.00265897",
      "EURUSD":"1.07905",
      "USDEUR":"0.92674",
      "KZTEUR":"0.00246431",
      "EURKZT":"405.817"
   }
}
```

*Результат который я получаю в итоге:* [image: Скриншот.]

*Мой Model(POJO) класс:*

```
public class ExchangeModel {


    @SerializedName("USDRUB")
    private String usdrub;

    @SerializedName("RUBUSD")
    private String rubusd;

    @SerializedName("EURRUB")
    private String eurrub;

    @SerializedName("RUBEUR")
    private String rubeur;

    @SerializedName("KZTRUB")
    private String kztrub;

    @SerializedName("RUBKZT")
    private String rubkzt;

    @SerializedName("USDKZT")
    private String usdkzt;

    @SerializedName("KZTUSD")
    private String kztusd;

    @SerializedName("EURUSD")
    private String eurusd;

    @SerializedName("USDEUR")
    private String usdeur;

    @SerializedName("KZTEUR")
    private String kzteur;

    @SerializedName("EURKZT")
    private String eurkzt;

    public String getUsdrub() {
        return usdrub;
    }

    public void setUsdrub(String usdrub) {
        this.usdrub = usdrub;
    }

    public String getRubusd() {
        return rubusd;
    }

    public void setRubusd(String rubusd) {
        this.rubusd = rubusd;
    }

    public String getEurrub() {
        return eurrub;
    }

    public void setEurrub(String eurrub) {
        this.eurrub = eurrub;
    }

    public String getRubeur() {
        return rubeur;
    }

    public void setRubeur(String rubeur) {
        this.rubeur = rubeur;
    }

    public String getKztrub() {
        return kztrub;
    }

    public void setKztrub(String kztrub) {
        this.kztrub = kztrub;
    }

    public String getRubkzt() {
        return rubkzt;
    }

    public void setRubkzt(String rubkzt) {
        this.rubkzt = rubkzt;
    }

    public String getUsdkzt() {
        return usdkzt;
    }

    public void setUsdkzt(String usdkzt) {
        this.usdkzt = usdkzt;
    }

    public String getKztusd() {
        return kztusd;
    }

    public void setKztusd(String kztusd) {
        this.kztusd = kztusd;
    }

    public String getEurusd() {
        return eurusd;
    }

    public void setEurusd(String eurusd) {
        this.eurusd = eurusd;
    }

    public String getUsdeur() {
        return usdeur;
    }

    public void setUsdeur(String usdeur) {
        this.usdeur = usdeur;
    }

    public String getKzteur() {
        return kzteur;
    }

    public void setKzteur(String kzteur) {
        this.kzteur = kzteur;
    }

    public String getEurkzt() {
        return eurkzt;
    }

    public void setEurkzt(String eurkzt) {
        this.eurkzt = eurkzt;
    }


    @SerializedName("status")
    private Integer status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


}
```

*Мой APICall интерфейс:*

```
public interface APICall {

    @GET("?get=rates&pairs=USDRUB,RUBUSD,EURRUB,RUBEUR,KZTRUB,RUBKZT,USDKZT,KZTUSD,EURUSD,USDEUR,KZTEUR,EURKZT,RUBKZT,KZTRUB&key=423ccabe7688caa88b8fc71edf90fb48")
    Call<ExchangeModel> getExchange();
}
```

Класс в котором я получаю и вывожу данные:

```
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://currate.ru/api/";

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APICall apiCall = retrofit.create(APICall.class);

    Call<ExchangeModel> myCall = apiCall.getExchange();

        myCall.enqueue(new Callback<ExchangeModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ExchangeModel> call, Response<ExchangeModel> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textView.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                String result = "";
               result = " USD - RUB Exchange: " + response.body().getUsdrub() + " Status: " + response.body().getStatus();

               textView.setText(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ExchangeModel> call, Throwable t) {
                textView.setText("ERROR!" + t);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Буду рад если редакторы подправят мой вопрос, ибо давно не задавал их здесь. Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто переделайте структуру вашего класса так, чтобы `Data` - был вложенным классом.
а лучше, пользуйтесь онлайн генераторами, вроде этого

https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo

Comment: Спасибо, пользовался как раз таки онлайн генератором, но совсем другим, попробую ваш способ!

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ! Я и не думал что решение настолько простое! Благодарю галочкой!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае `data` - это `Map<String, String>`
Поэтому pojo класс будет выглядеть так:

```
public class ExchangeModel {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private Integer status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private Map<String, String> data;

    //геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

Генераторы не всегда могут нормально сконвертить json в pojo. Они будут генерить дополнительный класс Data, в котором будут все поля из json. Проблема в том, что количество этих полей будет динамическим, и придётся всё время такой класс поддерживать, добавлять поля, обновлять приложение.

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение более практично, но мне главное чтобы хоть как-то 
пока что работало, ещё раз благодарю и возьму на заметку!